# How do i duplicate variables and functions and state in react.js?

Tags: reactjs

I want to know how duplicate functions and variables and useState that I'm using them as same thing.

and this is parents component so i can pass props to another component.
so This is the code :

```js
 const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [getId, setGetId] = useState([]);
  const [value, setValue] = useState([]);
  const [info, setInfo] = useState([]);
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState("");
  const [disabledTwo, setDisabledTwo] = useState("");
  const clickCheck = header => e => {
    setValue([...value, e.currentTarget.value]);
    setGetId([...getId, e.currentTarget.id]);
  };

  let chartData = {
    labels: ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""], //
    datasets: [
      {
        label: title,
        data: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], //
        backgroundColor: [
          "rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)",
          "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)",
          "rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)",
          "rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)",
          "rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)",
          "rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)",
        ],
      },
    ],
  };
  if (value[0] === "x") {
    chartData.labels = info.map(i => i[getId[0]]).slice(1, undefined);
  }
  if (value[0] === "y") {
    chartData.datasets[0].data = info.map(i => i[getId[0]]).slice(1, undefined);
  }
  if (value[1] === "x") {
    chartData.labels = info.map(i => i[getId[1]]).slice(1, undefined);
  }
  if (value[1] === "y") {
    chartData.datasets[0].data = info.map(i => i[getId[1]]).slice(1, undefined);
  }
  const changeData = () => {
    if (value[0] === "x" || value[1] === "x") {
      setDisabled("true");
    }
    if (value[0] === "y" || value[1] === "y") {
      setDisabledTwo("true");
    }
  };
  useEffect(changeData, [value]);
  const resetArray = () => {
    setValue([]);
    setGetId([]);
    setDisabled("");
    setDisabledTwo("");
  };

  const chartArray = [
    <Line
      key="o"
      data={chartData}
      options={{ responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false }}
    />,
    <Bar
      key="p"
      data={chartData}
      options={{ responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false }}
    />,
    <Pie
      key="q"
      data={chartData}
      options={{ responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false }}
    />,
    <Radar
      key="r"
      data={chartData}
      options={{ responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false }}
    />,
    <Doughnut
      key="s"
      data={chartData}
      options={{ responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false }}
    />,
    <Scatter
      key="t"
      data={chartData}
      options={{ responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false }}
    />,
    <PolarArea
      key="u"
      data={chartData}
      options={{ responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false }}
    />,
    <Bubble
      key="v"
      data={chartData}
      options={{ responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false }}
    />,
  ];
```

and What I tried to do is just copy and paste whole thing at below like this:

```js
 ....
 const [disabled2, setDisabled2] = useState("");
  const [disabledTwo2, setDisabledTwo2] = useState("");
  const clickCheck2 = title => e => {
    setValue2([...value2, e.currentTarget.value]);
    setGetId2([...getId2, e.currentTarget.id]);
  };

  let chartData2 = {
    labels: ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""], 
    datasets: [
      {
      ......
```

but the problem is that I have to use it for 7times more.
and the code was getting big..
So I want to know how to duplicate it without copy and paste .

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Why not simply invoke the component twice, seven times, or 500 times if necessary (in a loop), from the parent component?

Comment: It's main component and i need to pass to another component

Comment: Okay, then why not pass it `n` times to the other component? A big part of the point of components is reusability -- write it once, use it as many times as necessary without copy-pasting all of the code inside of it. I'd need more details to understand why this isn't possible in this case (I'm sure it is... basically, you never need to do `foo1`, `foo2`, `foo3` with correct design).

Comment: How can i pass `n times to the other component?` ?? that's what i want to know ! if there is reference, would u tell me what i should learn??

Comment: It depends on your use case, but typically use an array. Does your other component accept this as a prop (poor design, probably) or as a child? For example: `<OtherComponent>{Array(5000).fill().map(() => <MyComponent />)}</OtherComponent>` to wrap your other component around this one 5000 times (you'd probably have some dynamic properties you'd pass to `MyComponent` on each iteration using some data array -- I have no idea what your use case is without a crisper explanation and a [mcve] if you can provide it). A lot of the information in your code here isn't relevant to the question.

Comment: Yes it does ! it accept it as a child  hahaha .(It's poor design as well ) i need to redesign and learn about how to make minimal explanation ! thanks !

Answer (score 0):

A class component with setState may be more useful for what you want